# Listboxes in c#

Tags: c#

I have a form with two listboxes, listbox1 & listbox2. On form load I am filling up both the list boxes with same no. of items.
I want that if I select item at index 1 in listbox1 then in listbox2 item with the same index should also be selected.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: The question is not clear enough, as I understand if I select item 1 from list 1 then item 2 from list 2 will be selected also? so if I select item 2 from list 1 then item 3 from list 2 will be selected?

Comment: have you tried anything so far? you can do something like this `listBox2.SelectedIndex = listBox2.SelectedIndex + 1;`

Comment: Is it WinForms or WPF we are talking about?

Comment: do you want to select the item whose index is 2?

Comment: I think you mean combo box. If you mean list box, then following link explains all the API's in LisBox on windows forms application https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe on both listboxes `SelectionChanged` event and then set the `SelectedIndex` accordingly for the opposite listbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `SelectedIndex` in listBox2 to the `SelectedIndex` in listBox1.

Like so:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" />
<ListBox SelectedIndex="Binding ElementName=listBox1,Path=SelectedIndex" />
```

However, if you want to reflect the selection change on the listBox2 back to listBox1, you can't just do the same binding in listBox1, because it will throw StackOverflowException. You should subscribe to the SelectionChanged event on listBox2 and change the SelectedIndex of listBox1 in code.

Like so:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox2" SelectedIndex="Binding ElementName=listBox1,Path=SelectedIndex" SelectionChanged="listBox2_SelectionChanged" />
```

And the event handler method looks like this:

```
private void listBox2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox2.SelectedIndex;
}
```